# IDE that allows you to select text in both directions with keyboard arrow keys

Tags: text, ide, selection, arrow-keys

I'm looking for an IDE/code editor plugin that allows you to select text outwards from the cursor in both directions.

Eg: I have the following text in my IDE:

Mississippi

I place my cursor in the middle of the word Mississippi:

Missis**|**sippi

Now I want to hold a hot-key combination (e.g. Alt+Shift) to essentially lock my cursor in place...and then I want to press the left arrow key 6 times to select "Missis" to the left of my cursor......and press the right arrow key 5 times to select "sippi" to the right of my cursor.

Normally by using Shift+Arrow key...you move the cursor in a direction selecting everything as you go along. This way would essentially require two additional cursors so that after selecting the whole word in the fashion described above it'd look something like this:

**|**Missis**|**sippi**|**

Three cursors: The locked one, the one that moved left and the one that moved right...

If anyone knows whether this can/has been achieved in any IDE please let me know :)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Ctl-Left, Ctl-Shift-Right will achieve what you want with any IDE I know.

Comment: I imagine that would prove a bit odd to some people. Most people are used to selecting in one direction and then using the other direction to deselect any extra characters not wanted. What if the user selects the wrong chars? Do they have to release the Shift, hit the right or left key, then place the caret and try again?

Comment: @Eugen Rieck But that's only if the person using the editor wants to select a specific word. I'm not sure that that is what the OP is asking.

Comment: @MichaelTodd This was how I understood the OPs use case. If the "word select" was just a non-typical example, please disregard my comment. In this case I can only recommend EMACS, of which I am sure you can easily write such a function for. The learning curve might be a bit steep though.

Comment: what do you want to happen if you do this: hold alt+shift, press left 6 times, press right 5 times, **press left 1 time**. does that final key stroke move the right cursor to the left, making the last `i` no longer selected, or does it move the left cursor further to the left?

Comment: @MichaelTodd You're right my intention is not always to select a whole word. There are many ways to achieve that in most IDE's of course.

Comment: @EugenRieck Thanks for the suggestion, I figured I might come up against the "write it yourself" suggestion as this is a pretty obscure request :P

Comment: @davogotland I'd want the left cursor to move further left. I see what you mean, there'd be no reversing out of this...but at the moment I'd be ok with that.